# R: How to use haven with somewhat broken data

Tags: r, r-haven

I have some German data that contains umlaut, most importantly it seems to have wrong encoding.

#### Loading with `read.dta`

If I try straight on

```
> t <- read.dta(fileName)
Error in factor(rval[[v]], levels = tt[[ll[v]]], labels = names(tt[[ll[v]]])) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 4 should be 1 or 3
```

So I do instead

```
t <- read.dta(fileName, convert.factors = FALSE)
> head(t)
    persnr    betnr idnum    begorig    endorig     begepi     endepi frau gebjahr nation nation_gr famst
1 65170081 51705278    36 2000-01-01 2000-12-31 2000-01-01 2000-12-31    0    1967      0        10    NA
2 65170081 51705278    36 2001-01-01 2001-12-31 2001-01-01 2001-12-31    0    1967      0        10    NA
3 65170081 51705278    36 2002-01-01 2002-12-31 2002-01-01 2002-12-31    0    1967      0        10    NA
4 65170081 51705278    36 2003-01-01 2003-12-31 2003-01-01 2003-12-31    0    1967      0        10    NA
5 65170081 51705278    36 2004-01-01 2004-12-31 2004-01-01 2004-12-31    0    1967      0        10    NA
6 65170081 51705278    36 2005-01-01 2005-12-31 2005-01-01 2005-12-31    0    1967      0        10    NA
```

#### Loading with `read_dta`

Here's using the `haven` package:

```
>x <- read_dta(fileName)
>head(x)
Error: `x` and `labels` must be same type
> str(pers)
Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':   361921 obs. of  45 variables:
```

I don't understand the Error that I'm getting when using `head()`. I get the same error when trying to convert it to a data table using

```
data.table(read_dta(fileName))
```

When I do this, I will first see the error, and `R` will subsequently crash.

#### Test data:

The data file is contained [in this zip file](http://doku.iab.de/fdz/liab/LIAB_LM_9310_v1_test_dta.zip) and is called `LIAB_lm_9310_v1_pers.dta`.

Comment: It's hard to help without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MrFlick Right, I've linked some testing data.

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/haven/issues/26

Comment: @Metrics I've updated to the current Github version, the issue persists.